# Using mongodb-driver-sync from build.gradle

Tags: java, mongodb, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I have a task in which I have to use Gradle's test listener to log data about Junit Tests and dump them in a mongo database. I had installed the mongodb-driver-sync library and included it in the dependencies block of the build.gradle. The build.gradle looks as follows:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

tasks.regsister("connectToMongoDB") {
    doLast {
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");
        println(database.getName())
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.9.0'
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.2')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.2'
}
```

But this throws me the error `unable to resolve class com.mongodb.client.MongoClients`.

I also have run `./gradlew clean` `./gradlew build`, reloaded all the gradle projects in IntelliJ IDEA.

I want to know whether this is even possible or not? If it is then how or should I look form some different approach.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to add package `mongodb-driver-core` along

it would be like

```
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:4.11.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.11.0'
}
```

I am not sure why [official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/quick-start/#add-mongodb-as-a-dependency) does not say about this. If they just forgot, I would be very upset since I spent 2 days solving this issue.

I think a lot of developers are still using legacy [mongo-java-driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver) because of this issue. sad